# how can i set function.prototype.property using function name

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a printName function as below:

```
function printName(name) {
  console.log('Name is': , name);
}
```

Now i want to execute `printName.callAfter(3000, 'foo')`, which should log

> 'Name is: foo' after 3 seconds.

I tried writing :

```
myName.prototype.callAfter = function(time, name) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    printName(name)
  }, time);
}
```

But its only giving me *myName.prototype.callAfter* as a defined function but myName.callAfter is undefined.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: In your `printName` function, where does `name` come from? Did you mean to accept it as a parameter, or use `this.`, or is it really from the containing context?

Comment: `myName` isn't defined by your code. You should be getting a reference error. Try providing a [mcve]

Comment: @jass: `printName` in your question accepts no parameters. So again: Did you mean it to have `name` in its parameter list? If so, please edit the question to fix that. Live examples also belong **in** the question (via Stack Snippets, the `[<>]` toolbar button), not on other sites. Off-site links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: oops, sorry my bad.yes it accepts name as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prototype you should be applying to is (literally) `Function` not the *name of the function*. When you do this you can then execute `callAfter` on any defined function.

The below appears to do what you wanted.

```js
function printName(name) {
  console.log('Name is: ' , name);
}

Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "callAfter", {
  value: function(delay, args) {
    var func = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      func.apply(func,args);
    }, delay);
  }
});
printName("Instant");
printName.callAfter(3000,["After 3 seconds"]);
```

*(I'm using `Object.defineProperty` there so that `callAfter` isn't *enumerable*, which is frequently important when extending built-in prototypes.)*

You should be aware that extending built-in objects has some gotchas to be aware of.

- [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)
- http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/

Comment: Thanks for clarification. That is what I literally wanted to use :)

Answer (score -1):

I think I have what you want working in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kd13ugwt/

```
function printName(name) {
  console.log('Name is: ' , name);
}

printName.callAfter = function(time, name) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    printName(name)
  }, time);
}

printName.callAfter(3000, 'foo');
```